# Allow mixed content inside iframe

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, mixed-content

The parent site running on **https**. Inside parent site window a iframe with src **https**. The iframe has links with **http**.

Its https(main parent site) => https(iframe) => http(links inside iframe) scenario.

In browser console **blocked:mixed content** getting logged.

[image]

Kindly help to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 2):

this is a browser setting and you did not indicate which browser you are using.  Here is info from Firefox on how to [disable](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox) mixed-content blocking.  Note, disabling this increases your security risks.  Here is a good [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) describing the concept so you have a better understanding of why its happening and what the risks are.