# java request redirect https to http and content will not be loaded in iframe

Tags: java, ajax, http, iframe, https

I developed an application. In that some modules are exist on cloud server which are accessible to using `https` protocol and some modules are in my local server which are accessible to using `http` protocol.

So when i request `http` protocol to `https` protocol, it is working fine and i'm getting data also without any problem.

But once i redirect to `https` protocol than i want to access my another module which is on local server e.g. `http` protocol, So when i hit url or call to access local module  that time i'm getting this `error`.

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 
 'https://here is my url https machine ' was loaded over HTTPS, 
 but requested an insecure form action 'http:// here is my local url'. 
 This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

and it is not redirecting to `http` protocol.

How to solve this problem?

Anybody can help on this.

Thank you...

Comment: Did you also have a question?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yup this is question and now i looking for best ans to do this.

Comment: What's the question? I only read statements of fact.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ofcourse just understand the fact and give the solution. hot to solve this error.

Comment: Serve both your local and your cloud stuff over either HTTP or HTTPS, or configure your browser to allow active mixed content.

Comment: this was addressed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954623/allow-mixed-content-inside-iframe/41962553#41962553